# Empty Android folder when cloning Google samples

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I clone a Google sample repository from Github, the **Android project sidebar is completely empty** (No app folder and an empty Gradle folder). I usually encounter this problem when Android Studio asks me to provide the Gradle Home path when importing. I would highly appreaciate any help regarding solving this problem.

[Android studio 3.0 project with an empty Android folder view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfe8g.png)

E.g. cloning [Android vision API Samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are importing the project into Android Studio (like in the following picture), are you importing the entire Github repository or just a specific vision sample? You should be doing the latter. 
[Example of importing project into Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXUmh.png)

Let me know if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Your suggestion saved me a lot of struggle, thank you! Importing a specific sample did the trick.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!